# Can't get Nginx reverse proxy to find static files with multiple upstream servers

Tags: nginx

I have Nginx setup as a reverse proxy but I can't seem to serve static files on one of the upstream servers. Here are the important parts of my nginx conf file:

```
http {

include mime.types;

upstream dashboard {
    server dashboard:80;
}

upstream editor {
    server editor:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://dashboard;
    }

    location /editor/ {
        rewrite ^/editor(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://editor;
    }  
}
```

Both `dashboard` and `editor` are docker containers containing `create-react-app` applications being served by their own nginx servers. The `dashboard` application works but I receive 404 errors when the `editor` app attempts to load its static assets (.css, .js, etc):

[image]

I tried adding an additional location block to my nginx conf to catch requests for static assets and try each of the upstreams:

```
location ~* .(ico|jpg|png|gif|jpeg|css|swf|js|woff)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /editor/; 
}
```

I'm not sure what this is doing to be honest but the effect is that the static assets are now successfully found for both the `dashboard` and `editor` servers but incorrectly interpreted as text files:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://example.com/static/css/2.8271af8e.chunk.css"
```

I have no idea why the addition of this extra location block would cause that, however, as I've include the necessary `mime.types` file. At this point I'm completely baffled by what Nginx is doing with my requests for static files.

Can someone please suggest a fix OR provide an explanation of why the extra location block causes the assets to be found but incorrectly interpreted as text files?

Comment: You're using suburls instead of subdomain on incompatible apps. Either the `editor` upstream is capable of handling the fact it's not on / and you need to set it up, either you can create a subdomain for the various services you host.

Comment: As for the reinterpretation of the file types, the first step towards debugging this would be to remove the offending location and try hitting the /editor/<whatever ststaic file> to make sure it's interpreted correctly in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. In the end I changed the folder locations to the static assets for the `dashboard` and `editor` apps. Then rather than pattern matching on image/font/js/css files I added two separate location blocks to handle requests for those resources. Setting up subdomains is not an option for me, unfortunately. I never got to the bottom of why the file types were being misinterpreted.